# Custom button and wrapping multiple elements in a set of tags in TinyMCE or CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce-4, ckeditor4.x

I've been playing around with a number of WYSIWYG HTML editors and have found TinyMCE and CKEditor closest to meeting my requirements. However, I can't seem to add an extra button for wrapping multiple elements with either one using their API. I tried using a style to do the wrapping but, both wraps each selected element separately rather than as a group.

So when I highlight and click the new custom button on...

```
<p>Para 1</p>
<p>Para 2</p>
```

Instead of...

```
<div class="copy">
<p>Para 1</p>
<p>Para 2</p>
</div>
```

I get...

```
<div class="copy">
    <p>Para 1</p>
</div>

<div class="copy">
    <p>Para 2</p>
</div>
```

What are the API calls I need to achieve the former in either of these editors?

For TinyMCE v4.2 I tried:

```
ed = tinymce.init({
    selector: "#editor",
    toolbar: 'toolbar',
    setup: function(ed) {
    ed.addButton('wrapper', {
        text: 'testing',
        title : 'Wrapper',
        onclick : function() {
            ed.dom.setOuterHTML('p', '<div class="copy">checked</div>');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

For CKEditor v4.5:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor;

editor.addCommand( 'wrapcopy', {
    exec: function( editor ) {

    // try 1

    range = editor.getSelection().getRanges()[0];
    el = new CKEDITOR.dom.element('div');
    el.addClass('copy');

    el.append( range.cloneContents() );
    new_html = el.getOuterHtml();

    editor.insertHtml(new_html);                    
    return;

    // try 2

    elem = editor.getSelectedHtml();
    editor.insertHtml( '<div class="copy">'+editor.getSelectedHtml(true)+'</div>' );

    }
});

editor.ui.addButton( 'Wrapper', {
    label: 'Wrap',
    command: 'wrapcopy',
    toolbar: 'basicstyles,1'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I done this like:

```
// Adds a custom button to the editor that inserts contents when clicked
tinymce.init({
   ...

   toolbar: 'example'

   setup: function(ed) {
//add my custom command
      ed.addCommand('set-codeblock', function(ui, v) {
         ed.insertContent( '<pre><code>' + 
         ed.selection.getContent({format: 'text'}) + '</code></pre>' );
      }); 

//add my custom button
      ed.addButton('my-codeblock', {
         title: 'My title when cursor hover',
         text: 'Wrap code',
         onclick: function() {
//execute command by event click in button
            ed.execCommand('set-codeblock');
         }
      });
   }
});
```

And register button in toolbar:

```
'toolbar': "my-codeblock | undo redo |...
```